# Practicing Hadoop in local machine

Tags: hadoop

I have a pc with windows 8.1 and  ubuntu 12.04 os . Hardware specification is core i3 with 4 GB of Ram. 
Now i want to practice hadoop in my local pc. Is my current system is competitive with the hadoop framework available in the market. I am little bit confused. I went through may tutorial but they proposed software that is not applicable to my current system. So what can i do now .

Comment: `So what can i do now ` buy a new pc?

Comment: Is there any light weight software package for hadoop ??

Answer (score 0):

you can install hadoop on the system. go through this link which describes about "installation of hadoop on single node(computer)". it will help
"http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-single-node-cluster/"